# Is it possible to filter odata on collection property of a expanded entity

Tags: filter, odata, expand, odata-v4

I have a entity, `[Part]`,
which has a navigation property `[Representation]`
and in the entity `[Representation]` there is a property `[Files]`, which is entity file array
my question is : 
is is possible to filter the Part on the for which Representation.Files has `filetype='pdf'`
I tried this but failed

```
  Part?$filter=Representation/any(r:r/Files/filetype eq 'pdf')&$expand=representation
```

#### $metadata extract:

```xml
<EntityType Name="Part" BaseType="Entity">
  <NavigationProperty Name="Representations" Type="Collection(Representation)"> </NavigationProperty>
</EntityType>
<EntityType Name="Representation"> 
  <Property Name="AdditionalFiles" Type="Collection(RepresentationHyperlink)"> </Property> 
</EntityType>
```

> **Note:** `Files` is a property with an array type, it is **not** a *navigation* property.

Comment: What version of OData are you operating in?

Comment: You should post the error message that you receive too, on OData the errors are almost always meaningful

Answer (score 2):

In OData v4, if `Files` was a *Collection* navigation property then the following will work:

```
...Part?$filter=Representation/Files/any(f:f/filetype eq 'pdf')&$expand=representation
```

The `any` function operates on the many navigation link, so it should appear immediately after it, not before it.

## Not Supported

Due to `Files` ***NOT*** being a collection property, and instead being an *array **value***, this is outside of the scope of the OData v4 spec.

Some API implementations do support *array values in the **model*** however this is usually achieved through fancy mapping in the OData configuration, from an OData point of view these properties have to be expressed as Collection properties for [lambda operators](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part2-url-conventions.html#_Toc444868730) to evaluate.

---

An alternate solution in this scenario is to create a *function* on the controller to handle this request specifically, either to pass in the file type to filter on or make an explicit function that returns just the `pdf` representations.

Comment: It does not works, returns URI is malformed.
probably because the files is not a navgation property? It normal property but data type is object array.

Comment: What backend database engine are you using? In your question can you post the `$metadata` for the `Part` and `Representation`. The above syntax works on navigation properties only, but we may be able to expose `Files` as a _pseudo_ Collection (of either _Entity_ or _ComplexType_)

Comment: it is the Odata v4, please see the part of metadata
<EntityType Name="Part" BaseType="Entity">
 <NavigationProperty Name="Representations" Type="Collection(Representation)">

 </NavigationProperty>    
</EntityType>

<EntityType Name="Representation">
 <Property Name="AdditionalFiles" Type="Collection(RepresentationHyperlink)">  
 </Property>
</EntityType>